# How to load only required template in IonicFramework

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

I am getting two flow in my two diff codes.
I am developing an [ionicframework](http://ionicframework.com/) based app using its default (angular based [`ui-router`](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router)) routing.
Now when i coded for the ionic this way.

```
*.config(["$stateProvider","$urlRouterProvider",function ($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider) {

        $urlRouterProvider
            .otherwise('oops');
        $stateProvider
            .state('dashboard',{
                    url:"/dashboard",
                    abstract: true,
                    templateUrl:'templates/dashboard.html',
                    controller:"myCtrl"
                })
            .state('courses',{
                    url:'/courses',
                    templateUrl:'templates/courses.html',
                    controller:'myCtrl'
                })
            .state('transactions',{
                    url:'/transactions',
                    templateUrl:'templates/transactions.html'
                })
            .state('oops',{
                url:'/oops',
                templateUrl:'templates/oops.html',
                controller:'myCtrl'
            })
        }])*
```

view :

```
<ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
```

i found all my templates are getting loaded at once (on browser console testing) when i call my base route (also for any route,whichever i called for the first load of app).

where as when i use the ui-router for the nonionic app like :

```
myApp.config(function($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider){

    /*throw the rest url to home page*/
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/single");

    $stateProvider
        .state("single",{
            url:"/single",
            templateUrl:"templates/single.html"
        })
        .state("portfolio",{
            url:'/portfolio',
            templateUrl:'templates/portfolio.html',
            controller:"myCtrl"
        })
        .state("nested",{
            url:"/nested",
            templateUrl:"templates/nested.html"
            }
        )
        .state("nested.viwe1",{
            url:"/view1",
            templateUrl:"templates/nested.view1.html"
        })
        .state("nested.viwe2",{
            url:"/view2",
            templateUrl:"templates/nested.view2.html"
        })

});
```

view:

```
<div ui-view class="my-element"></div>
```

only the demanded templates (configured with the route),is getting loaded.
So is the Ionic loads all template initially or else i am flowing wrong with the code.

Answer (score 4):

Return the `templateUrl` by a function. Like this,

```
templateUrl: function() {return 'templates/courses.html';}
```

https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/3819

http://ionicframework.com/docs/platform-customization/dynamic-templates.html